# Is there a way of using PHP PDO::quote method without creating a connection?

Tags: php, pdo, quote

I've been using [PDO::quote](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) to generate SQL statements. I use the generated SQL to create a `memcached` key. I'd like to avoid having to create a connection solely for the purpose of escaping SQL values.

What is the purpose of needing to establish a connection to use PDO::quote method and can it be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

Because PDO is an abstraction layer, and each database's quoting methods differ. PDO must know WHICH database you're going to be using to be able to use the proper quoting/escaping API calls.

Comment: You'd think there would be some way to just pass a local config to PDO rather than making an extra connection to a remote database just to check that.

Answer (score 1):

You need a connection because the notion of escaping variables only makes sense when in the context of a database connection with respect to which they are to be escaped. Different characters might be interpreted differently, say, by MySQL and PostgreSQL, or depending on the character set of the connection. So it does not make sense to talk about escaping variables in a vacuum, you need some notion of how the resulting string will be interpreted.

Maybe you could use something else as a key to memcached.

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense to talk about escaping in a vacuum, but to make a connection to the db just for quoting seems like an overkill. I understand that it needs db parameters, but those are in the PDO constructor. I'm using postgresql... I think I'll use a custom quote when the connection is not already created

Answer (score 1):

If you know the driver that the SQL is going to be used with, just write a function of your own, e.g.

```
/**
 * @param {string|int|null} $data
 * @return string
 */
function quote ($data) {
    if (is_float($data) || is_int($data)) {
        return $data;
    } else if (is_string($data)) {
        return '\'' . addslashes($data) . '\'';
    } else if ($data) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid data type.');
    } else {
        return 'NULL';
    }
}
```

An example use case: You have a CLI program that is used to generate SQL code that will be executed later by another program. In this scenario, establishing MySQL connection is redundant and might be unwanted.